# Add file content in another file after first match only

Tags: bash, sed

Using bash, I have this line of code that adds the content of a temp file into another file, after a specific match:

```
sed -i "/text_to_match/r ${tmpFile}" ${fileName}
```

I would like it to add the temp file content only after the FIRST match.

I tried using addresses:

```
sed -i "0,/text_to_match//text_to_match/r ${tmpFile}" ${fileName}
```

But it doesn't work, saying that "/" is an unknown command.

I can make addresses work if I use a standard replacement "s/to_replace/with_this/", but I can't make it work with this sed command.
It seems like I can't use addresses if my sed command starts with `/` instead of a letter.

I'm not stuck with addresses, as long as I can insert the temp file content into another file only once.

Comment: Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting that error because if you have an address range (ADDR1,ADDR2) you can't put another address after it: sed expects a command there and `/` is not a command.

You'll want to use some braces here:

```
$ seq 20 > file
$ echo "new content" > tmpFile
$ sed '0,/5/{/5/ r tmpFile
}' file
```

outputs the new text only after the first line with '5'

```
1
2
3
4
5
new content
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

I found I needed to put a newline after the filename. I was getting this error otherwise

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'
```

It appears that sed takes the whole rest of the line as the filename.

Probably more tidy to write

```
sed '0,/5/ {
    /5/ r tmpFile 
}' file
```

---

Full transparency: I don't use sed except for very simple tasks. In reality I would use awk for this job

```
awk '
    {print} 
    !seen && $0 ~ patt {
        while (getline line < f) print line
        close(f)
        seen = 1
    }
'  patt="5" f=tmpFile file
```

Comment: GNU sed allows the second `/5/` to be `//`, shorthand which would help if the pattern match is long.  Not sure if that's just GNU.

Answer (score 2):

[Glenn Jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55420712/8344060) provided with an excellent answer to why the OP's attempt did not work.

In continuation to Glenn Jackman's answer, if you want to have the command on a single line, you should use branching so that the `r` command is at the end.

> Editing commands other than `{...}`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `i`, `r`, `t`, `w`, `:`, and `#` can be followed by a <semicolon>, optional <blank> characters, and another editing command. However, when an `s` editing command is used with the `w` flag, following it with another command in this manner produces undefined results.
>  **<sup>[source: [POSIX sed Standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)]</sup>**
>
> The `r,R,w,W` commands parse the filename until end of the line. If whitespace, comments or semicolons are found, they will be included in the filename, leading to unexpected results.
> **<sup>[source: [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Multiple-commands-syntax)]</sup>**

which gives:

```
sed -e '1,/pattern/{/pattern/ba};b;:a;r rfile' file
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU sed also allows `s///e` to shell out.  So there's this one-liner using Glenn's tmpFile and file.

`sed '0,/5/{//{p;s/.*/cat tmpFile/e}}' file`

- `//` to repeat the previous pattern match (helps if it's longer than `/5/`)
- `p` to print the matching line
- `s/.*/cat tmpFile/e` to empty the pattern buffer and stick a the `cat tmpFile` shell command in there and `e` execute it and dump the output in the stream

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 forward slashes together, right next to each other in the second sed example.

Comment: Yes I know, and this is the cause of the error. But the adresses, if I'm not wrong, have this syntax: ```sed '0,/pattern/s/to_replace/with_this/'```. So I tried to use them with my ```sed '/pattern/r tempFile'``` but obviously it doesn't work. It doesn't work either if I remove one of these ```/```.